# How to achieve this xml?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I want to achieve like the image below

[image]

And I tried, but it is not my desired result.

[image]

Below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/input_register"
        android:text="Date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/ListDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="166dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/violetred" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> How can I write the ... beside the Amount TextView same like the first image I post ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would use constraint layout for this. Best way to go.

Comment: Create a horizontal linear layout and divide it in three parts using weights, and then proceed accordingly

Comment: A single RelativeLayout is more than enough. No need to nest useless LinearLayouts (nested layouts are bad for performances).

Comment: check the answer below do not use any hard coded values for width and height it will work for one screen not for all sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this helps you.exact xml of you want to achieve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/photo"
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:padding="3dp"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:layout_gravity="center"/>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_container"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:text="Description"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/photo" />

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/right_container"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/ListDate"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:textColor="@color/input_register"
           android:text="12-11-2017"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="777$"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textColor="@color/violetred" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nested layouts are bad for performances. You can do all with a single RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Rotwang i want `@+id/ListDate` and `@+id/ListAmount` center Vertical of of parent.thats why i nested layout. is there any different way to achieve this without nested layout?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can use a fake View which has 0dp width and height and position the elements around it.

Comment: @Rotwang Thanks!! its nice idea

Comment: @AI. Use google to find tutorials. I'm sure that w3schools has pretty good XML tutorials.

Comment: @AI. ... but I guess you actually want to learn android layouts, instead. Which is surely best learned on the android developers site.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve your requirement with this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#d8d8d8" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:background="#c8c8c8"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="2014-05-08"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="$600"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have only one layout which will solve your problem nesting is not a good idea.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:textColor="#000"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:textSize="?android:actionBarItemBackground"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:text="8 hours @ $80.00/hour"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="2014-05-08"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="?android:actionBarItemBackground"
            android:text="$640.00"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use constraint layout for best performance. If not, use horizontal linear layout, with weight on the center one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Buy drinks fvbfvfvfvasdasdasdfvfvvfvf" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="1014-05-08" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="$6969"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Nested layouts are bad for performances. You can do all with a single RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Rotwang i mentioned that for best performance, use constraint layout.

Comment: Never heard about constraint layout. Can it used as drag and drop?

Comment: @AI. yes, no XML editing required. Just drag and drop, and changing some values from the designer.

Comment: Thanks. Will try later :)

Comment: You mentioned. But then you proposed something different. Which is, again, bad for performances. Why providing the OP with a **suboptimal** soultion, while you know there's a better one?

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="ASASJHGHHBHHJHJNKMKIKMKMKMKMKKNIKNIJ" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2016-01-11" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$640"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nested layouts are bad for performances. You can do all with a single RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks for your review.Can you please tell me what issues it will create. So, I can think about alternative solution.@Rotwang

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:weightSum=".20"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum=".80"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/input_register"
        android:text="Date"

         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="DescriptionDescriptionDescriptionDescription"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/violetred" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks,but I want to have the ... beside the amount

Comment: Nested layouts are bad for performances. You can do all with a single RelativeLayout.